# Unlocking bootloader on Sony Ericsson NEO V

Tags: bootloader-lock

Has anybody managed to use Fastboot on Ubuntu to unlock the Sony Ericsson Neo V? I tried and got the blue led light (bootloader) while connecting the USB. But Fastboot still doesn't recognize the device. I did follow the instructions to check if it was unlockable and yes it is. Is there some compatibility issue between Ubuntu 11.04 and Fastboot??

p.s., I have managed to root the phone using the ADB script I found on xdaforums.

Comment: Check whether you installed ADB drivers.